# How to get all eigenvalues from sparse matrix with eigs_gen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, armadillo

I'm using Armadillo. The [`eigs_gen`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_gen) function (for `SpMat` sparse matrices) has a parameter `k` for the number of eigenvalues to compute.

I have a 3x3 matrix `my_matrix`, when I run

```
arma::cx_fvec values;
arma::cx_fmat vectors;

arma::eigs_gen (values, vectors, my_matrix, 3);
```

I get the following exception

```
eigs_gen(): n_eigvals + 1 must be less than the number of rows in the matrix
```

To have 3 eigenvalues for a 3x3 matrix is well-defined in general, so I don't understand this restriction.

On the other hand, the `eig_gen` function, which computes all eigenvalues, only compiles for the dense matrix `Mat` type.

How do I find all eigenvalues for a sparse matrix with Armadillo?

Comment: Since your matrix is tiny (3x3), use a dense matrix instead of a sparse matrix. Then use the [eig_gen()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_gen) function for dense matrices. (As the [docs for SpMat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) state, sparse matrices are only meant for "large matrices where only a small minority of the elements are non-zero". There is little point in finding all the eigenvectors of a sparse matrix, as this ends up with a dense matrix with the eigenvectors, which defeats the purpose of sparse matrices.)

Comment: @hbrerkere I know what dense/sparse matrices are for. This is something that my test suite exposed.The error message seems to indicate that you can only get the first 998 eigenvalues out of a 1,000-square matrix. This just seems odd.

Comment: @hbrerkere would it reduce memory? I would be interested in getting only some but I don't know beforehand how many are going to be significant.

Comment: @spraff You can get all eigenvalues if you want, at least with the newest version it worked for me. I have found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/283696/128094) how to determine how many are important if your matrix is normal.